# Regex exact match on number, not digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a scenario where I need to find and replace a number in a large string using javascript. Let's say I have the number 2 and I want to replace it with 3 - it sounds pretty straight forward until I get occurrences like 22, 32, etc.

The string may look like this:
`"note[2] 2 2_ someothertext_2 note[32] 2finally_2222 but how about mymomsays2."`

I want turn turn it into this:
`"note[3] 3 3_ someothertext_3 note[32] 3finally_2222 but how about mymomsays3."`

Obviously this means `.replace('2','3')` is out of the picture so I went to regex. I find it easy to get an exact match when I am dealing with string start to end ie: `/^2$/g`. But that is not what I have. I tried grouping, digit only, wildcards, etc and I can't get this to match correctly.

Any help on how to exactly match a number (where 0 <= number <= 500 is possible, but no constraints needed in regex for range) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does it matter if it matches `001` (eg: two leading zeros)

Comment: `exactly match a number (where 0 <= number <= 500)`  = `\d|[1-9]\d|[1-4]\d{2}|500`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task is to find (and replace) "single" digit 2, not embedded in
a number composed of **multiple** digits.

In regex terms, this can be expressed as:

- Match digit `2`.
- Previous char (if any) can not be a digit.
- Next char (if any) can not be a digit.

The regex for the first condition is straightforward - just `2`.
In other flavours of regex, e.g. *PCRE*, to forbid the previous
char you could use *negative lookbehind*, but unfortunately Javascript
regex does not support it.

So, to circumvent this, we must:

- Put a capturing group matching either start of text or something
  other than a digit: `(^|\D)`.
- Then put regex matching just *2*: `2`.

The last condition, fortunately, can be expressed as *negative lookahead*,
because even Javascript regex support it: `(?!\d)`.

So the whole regex is:

```
(^|\D)2(?!\d)
```

Having found such a match, you have to replace it with the content
of the first capturing group and *3* (the replacement digit).

Answer (score 2):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/iKHZ9N/3)

```
(\D|\b)2(?!\d)
```

- `(\D|\b)` Capture either a non-digit character or a position that matches a word boundary
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not a digit

Alternations:

```
(^|\D)2(?!\d)      # Thanks to @Wiktor in the comments below
(?<!\d)2(?!\d)     # At the time of writing works in Chrome 62+
```

```js
const regex = /(\D|\b)2(?!\d)/g
const str = `note[2] 2 2_ someothertext_2 note[32] 2finally_2222 but how about mymomsays2.`
const subst = "$13"

console.log(str.replace(regex, subst))
```

Comment: A variation of `(?<!\d)2(?!\d)` without lookarounds? Perhaps, `(^|\D)2(?!\d)` would be best here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew exactly. I guess I could use a lookahead. The lookbehind now works in Chrome though!

Comment: You can not use `(?<!\d)` (lookbehind) in Javascript regex, as Javascript does not support it.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo there's a note right next to it. It works in Chrome 62+ now and is currently in the works to becoming part of the ECMA standard. See [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-regexp-proposals) article summarizing the changes. Once two major browsers implement it, it'll become a standard (come on Firefox, let's make this a standard!)

Comment: The first version `(\D|\b)2(\D|\b)` will skip some valid `2` when they are only 1 character apart. You need at least one look-around.

Comment: @trincot you're very right. Replaced my original regex with the first alternation I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative look-ahead:

[`(\D|^)2(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/Zmrb52/2)

Replace with: `${1}3`

If look behind is supported:

[`(?<!\d)2(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/Zmrb52/3)

Replace with: `3`